# Debug apps in specific ROMS such as MIUI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine

I'm currently developing Android&iOS apps in my current company and I always struggled when it comes to test some features with different kind of ROMS, since in the company we don't have more than two different physical devices to try our code.

In example, I struggle so much when it comes about receiving push notifications using FCM in devices that belong to brands like Xiaomi, Huawei and Samsung (mainly because of power saving settings...).

Is there someone that knows if there is some kind of tool that help you to emulate some devices like the ones that I mentioned? I've tried some research about it but I couldn't find something that really fits to my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: There's places like Amazon (and others) that let you test on actual devices remotely.  You may want to check out that if you're having problems with specific models/brands.  Emulating specific devices is problematic, as you don't know what code they actually run for OSes, device drivers, etc.  They frequently have custom patches added.